# Struts2 redirectAction Glassfish 3+ Apache2 Rewrite rules

Tags: struts2, apache2, url-rewriting, glassfish-3

I have deployed a struts2 web application in glassfish. I access the app via `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. I have configured apache in order to access it via `http://mydomain.com`.

Everything works fine except for the redirectAction result in struts. It appends the context name again in the url, so the url looks like `http://mydomain.com/myapp/myaction`. How can I prevent this?

Comment: The problem is in your apache config.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080/myapp/$1 [P]

Comment: Can anyone provide any help??